# Handle many requests Web Services

Tags: java, tomcat

I created a web service with Jersey and Tomcat in localhost.

Now I want to expose my web services to all users in the world, so let's assume you have many concurrent requests.

I have access to a good physical blade server (4 CPU (8 cores)-32GB RAM, 600GB HD, etc. ..), only one.

I'm wondering, with a single physical server load balancing is useful? or proxy reserve? or only when you have multiple physical servers?

How should I manage the architecture with Tomcat and Jersey?

What are the possible solutions to handle many requests? pool of threads? but how i can do that with Jersey?

Comment: And this is code-related how? You should do research on your own first and then head to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) to discuss details.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering, with a single physical server load balancing is useful?

It is useless with an single server instance

> or proxy reserve?

That depends on your needs.

> or only when you have multiple physical servers?

Here load balancer is mostly in 100% cases mandatory, but still depends on your needs

> How should I manage the architecture with Tomcat and Jersey?

The same - what are the needs and requests?

> What are the possible solutions to handle many requests? pool of
>   threads? but how i can do that with Jersey?

Tomcat will take care of multi-threading.

Comment: i have for client an app android, and for server(tomcat+jersey). My problem now is figure out how i can handle many requests concurrent?. Example 100 user use my app for retrive something through a API from my web services, how i can handle that? i think a thread pool but i'm not sure how..or Async in Jersey? sorry my bad english

Comment: @FelasDroid tomcat is servlet container that takes care of multiple requests from multiple users. Each request will be passed to a service (jersey) which will respond on each request.

Comment: ThreadPools are used when whithin a single request you want to execute multiple tasks and those should not block each other, e.g: on user request you want to send an email, in that case it is bad practice to make client to wait until email is sent, here you will use threadpool.

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. Each API contain a web driver for simulate web browsing and return html source to a app. So each request i must open a headless browser and do some operation to navigate (Selenium). You think for better performance and not have a overload server, ThreadPool is a solution? or not?

Comment: Performance and Loading issues are worth of writing PhD dissertation. Assuming which hardware you have and in case you have service implemented 'like_in_a_doc' you won't receive any performance issues having amount of regular users of 200-300.